# If a question got asked again in another SE instead of being migrated to the new SE, what should we do?

Tags: discussion, migration

So [TLS handshake proof of private key posession](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143366/tls-handshake-proof-of-private-key-posession) got asked here initially but after a user's advice it got cross posted to crypto SE (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/tls-handshake-proof-of-private-key-posession) by the same user.
What do we do with the original question. A comment was already added in to the question saying that it has been asked again on the crypto SE and has been answered correctly there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically if a cross post has been answered well, and the answer is accepted on another site, we close it here.

If it has good answers and is accepted here, we'll usually keep it.

On occasion, however, we'll work with mods from the other site to migrate and merge - that's pretty rare, though, I think.

Comment: I'll flag this question to be closed then. Thanks!